How display the column name with Apostrophe in cfml
There is SP which returns the result with column name which have apostrophe i.e, isNotBM'd
I need to display the values of this column name in cfml page.
Here is the code
<CFQUERY name="get" DATASOURCE="Maste"> exec DB01.Log.Bmarking_History </cfquery> 
Column name we have is isNotBM'd
Below is the column name which i tried to display in cfml page
<cfoutput query="get"><TR class="tableItems"><TD>#["isNotBM'd"])#</TD></TR></cfoutput>

What actually happens when you run this code?

I believe, the easiest way to handle this scenario is to alias the column in select query/sp itself. I did try with different solutions but nothing else worked for me.
Select * , [isNotBM'd] as c2 from tablename


fetching data from SP , So changing the column name can't be done, Not sure if there is a way to do it.

I found the solution, this is how I tried to display the data:
#YesNoFormat(get["isNotBM'd"][currentRow])#

